# Mongoose not being able to install from CMD

Tags: cmd, mongoose, npm

I am trying to learn MEAN stack, i've installed Node,Express,and Angular on my PC using npm, i've also installed Mongo DB and now i am trying to install Mongoose, but i am not able to install it ! i am getting the following error in the command line ! please suggest me a way to install it

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\nishanth>npm install mongoose
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency kerberos@~0.0 included from         mongod
b-core will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the     peerD
ependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on     it
explicitly.

> kerberos@0.0.17 install     C:\Users\nishanth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\m
ongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

\
    C:\Users\nishanth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerber
os>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_module
s\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild     )
else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Python33", you can set th
e PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program      Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd     C:\Users\nishanth\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_m
odules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
v3.0.3! node-gyp -v-
gyp ERR! not ok
mongoose@4.3.5 node_modules\mongoose
├── ms@0.7.1
├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
├── async@0.9.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── muri@1.0.0
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── kareem@1.0.1
├── bson@0.4.19
├── mquery@1.6.3 (debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.9.26)
└── mongodb@2.1.2 (es6-promise@3.0.2, kerberos@0.0.17, mongodb-core@1.2.30,     read
able-stream@1.0.31)

C:\Users\nishanth>
```

Comment: While installing mongoose locally better is to create your project folder and go to that folder and then install all the npm packages which you required in your app.

Answer (score 1):

The above error clearly indicate that one of the dependency module `kerberos@0.0.17` require python as dependency for installation. But it not found in your environment path. Better you should install python and set the path in environment variable. Then try to install the mongoose inside your project directory.